# How to Avoid the Dreaded 'Select', 'Copy' & 'Paste' in this Example?

Tags: excel, vba

This works, but I know it is evil:

```
EIRPLLs.Select
Range(Cells(1, RevCol - 2), Cells(lastRevRow, RevCol + 3)).Copy
EIRPCases.Select
[A1:F1].Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

The below is intended to be equivalent, but results in Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed:

```
EIRPCases.Columns("A:F") = EIRPLLs.Range(Cells(1, RevCol - 2), Cells(lastRevRow, RevCol + 3)).Value
```

This also fails:

```
EIRPCases.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lastRevRow, 6)) = EIRPLLs.Range(Cells(1, RevCol - 2), Cells(lastRevRow, RevCol + 3)).Value
```

What is the correct implementation?

Comment: `Cells` are `Range` imply a reference to the `ActiveSheet`. If `EIRPCases` is not the `ActiveSheet` or part of it, the above fails.. @simoco's implementation is more robust.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do this one:

```
With EIRPLLs.Cells(1, RevCol - 2).Resize(lastRevRow, 6)
    EIRPCases.Range("A1").Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count).Value = .Value
End With
```

Comment: That is quite nifty. Resize is new to me and has nice qualities. Much thanks for yet another swift and helpful answer.